# How to create a new column in a dataframe depending on other columns values

Tags: r

I have a dataset about the years that different subjects took a certain treatment. I need to obtain a column that sets the first year of treatment and 0 if the subject has never been treated.

Let's say I have this dataset:

```
subject <- c(A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
treat <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(subject, year, treat)
```

I want to obtain this:

```
subject <- c(A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
treat <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
first_treat <- c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(subject, year, treat, first_treat)
```

In my original dataset I have mulriple subjects, so I would like to obtain a code to get this done without the need to mention rows or column values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by approach - grouped by 'subject', create a logical vector with `treat`, subset the 'year' and extract the first element (`[1]`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat = year[treat == 1][1]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   subject  year treat first_treat
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 a        2000     0        2003
 2 a        2001     0        2003
 3 a        2002     0        2003
 4 a        2003     1        2003
 5 a        2004     1        2003
 6 b        2000     0        2001
 7 b        2001     1        2001
 8 b        2002     1        2001
 9 b        2003     1        2001
10 b        2004     1        2001
11 c        2000     0          NA
12 c        2001     0          NA
13 c        2002     0          NA
14 c        2003     0          NA
15 c        2004     0          NA
```

---

If we want to return no year case as 0, an option is with `coalesce`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat = coalesce(year[treat == 1][1], 0)) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   subject  year treat first_treat
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 a        2000     0        2003
 2 a        2001     0        2003
 3 a        2002     0        2003
 4 a        2003     1        2003
 5 a        2004     1        2003
 6 b        2000     0        2001
 7 b        2001     1        2001
 8 b        2002     1        2001
 9 b        2003     1        2001
10 b        2004     1        2001
11 c        2000     0           0
12 c        2001     0           0
13 c        2002     0           0
14 c        2003     0           0
15 c        2004     0           0
```

Comment: In this case it happens the same as the first answer, I obtain the first_treat column as the first year that some subject was treated. That is, all the column has the same value in every cell. Hence, all the column would be filled with "2003".

Comment: @marcrocallevadot i couldn't follow your comment.  I guess the answer matches with your expected output

Comment: What I meant is that using this code I cannot obtain the desired outcome, since the new variable first_treat is (2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003) instead of (2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @marcrocallevadot I get the desired output though.  Maybe you have loaded `plyr` as well which masked `mutate`.  Try changing the `mutate` to `dplyr::mutate`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat = ifelse(1 %in% treat, year[treat==1], 0))
```

```
subject  year treat first_treat
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A        2000     0        2003
 2 A        2001     0        2003
 3 A        2002     0        2003
 4 A        2003     1        2003
 5 A        2004     1        2003
 6 B        2000     0        2001
 7 B        2001     1        2001
 8 B        2002     1        2001
 9 B        2003     1        2001
10 B        2004     1        2001
11 C        2000     0           0
12 C        2001     0           0
13 C        2002     0           0
14 C        2003     0           0
15 C        2004     0           0
```

Comment: By doing that, I obtain the first_treat column as the first year that some subject was treated. That is, all the column has the same value in every cell. In this case, all the column would be filled with "2003"